# multiple notifications on receiving gcm notification to different Activity

Tags: android

i am sending notification with 2 different method with different parameter 1,2   if we get parameter 1 then if we read notification from notification manger it should redirect to chatActvity and if we receive parameter 2 then it should redirect to Home activity when i read notification notification manger please help me where am doing wrong below is my code :

I am getting Message and all parameter when i Pus from server : i am unable to redirect to Home activity and chat activity

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    Context context;
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    public static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";
    String msg;
    String senderID;
    String recieverID;
    int value = 1;
    int reccvingparamtere;
    String time;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        senderID = intent.getStringExtra("sender_id");
        recieverID = intent.getStringExtra("reccvier_id");
        reccvingparamtere = intent.getIntExtra("reccvingparamtere",
                reccvingparamtere);
        time = intent.getStringExtra("time");
        // test=intent.getStringExtra("_test");
        SharedPreferences prefs = GcmIntentService.this.getSharedPreferences(
                AppConstants.LOGIN_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Chat chat = new Chat();
        chat.setMessage(msg);
        chat.setSenderID(senderID);
        chat.setRecieverID(prefs.getString(AppConstants.MEMBER_ID, ""));
        chat.setSenderName("");
        chat.setRecieverName("");
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(GcmIntentService.this);
        dbHelper.addMessage(chat);
        AppConstants.RECEIVED_MSG = msg;
        AppConstants.RECEIVED_RCVID = senderID;
        AppConstants.RECEIVED_SENDID = recieverID;
        AppConstants.RECEIVED_TIME = new Date().toString();
        GcmIntentService.this.sendBroadcast(intent);
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                    .equals(messageType)) {

                if (reccvingparamtere == 1) {

                    sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString(),
                            senderID);
                } else if (reccvingparamtere == 2) {
                    sendNotification2("Send error: " + extras.toString(),
                            senderID);
                }
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification(
                        "Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString(),
                        senderID);
                // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG,
                            "Working... " + (i + 1) + "/5 @ "
                                    + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                // Post notification of received message.
                // sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
                if (LociiApplication.FID.equals(senderID))
                    System.out.println("Dont show notifications!");
                else
                    sendNotification(msg, senderID);
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String msg, String sender_id) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent myintent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
        myintent.putExtra("message", msg);
        myintent.putExtra("to_id", sender_id);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                myintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.lokii_notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle("Locii Messge").setAutoCancel(true)
                // .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://package_name/raw/sound"))
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }

    private void sendNotification2(String msg, String sender_id) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent myintent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        myintent.putExtra("message", msg);
        myintent.putExtra("to_id", sender_id);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                myintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.lokii_notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle("Locii Messge").setAutoCancel(true)
                // .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://package_name/raw/sound"))
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the notification appear in your notification bar?

Comment: yes its coming when i push message from server

Comment: make sure that your activities are correctly inserted in your AndroidManifest.xml, including their package

Comment: yes it there alredy   <activity
            android:name="com.lociiapp.HomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.lociiapp.ChatActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

Comment: please check my code of GCmIntentservice class is it correct to re direct to send notification to two different class ?

Comment: @zozelfelfo  u thre plz help where am doing wrong or u have any Solution for this please suggest

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what it is wrong, but I can suggest you some points.

1. Include flags in your `Intent`

`myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

2 . Use a `TaskStackBuilder` to create your PendingIntent

```
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);

stackBuilder.addParentStack(SomeActivity.class);

Intent myintent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
myintent.putExtra("message", msg);
myintent.putExtra("to_id", sender_id);
myintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(myintent);


// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
     PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
             stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
                     PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                     );
 mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

// mId allows you to update the notification later on.
mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Let me try this and i will get back to You

Comment: can u please add it in mY code beacoz u dint create Intent and u are adding setfaag please edit with my code i have two class on chatactivity and another home activity

Comment: i am trying to implement it but not able to get @zozelfelfo

Comment: I create the Intent (for HomeActivity) you have to duplicate the code for your ChatActivity

Comment: stackBuilder.addParentStack(SomeActivity.class);  what about this Line ?

Comment: u there am confused about stackBuilder.addParentStack(SomeActivity.class);

Comment: You just need to type one activity there, your main Activity would fit there.

Comment: U mean i sud Put Chat Activity there?

Comment: please Update it with my code coz i am getting Error Some Point/ i think ur code will work but i am getting Error please update mY code for tboth activity